# Tympanus Elastislide Carousel autoplay

Tags: jquery

I am using tympanus Elastislide Carousel Responsive jQuery plugin for my website. The plugin works perfectly on my site. But, I want the casousel will play automacily.

But, I don't find any code for move carousel automatically.

The Slider Plugin link: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/09/12/elastislide-responsive-carousel/

The java script I am using

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $( '#carousel' ).elastislide( {

    // orientation 'horizontal' || 'vertical'
    orientation : 'horizontal',

    // sliding speed
    speed : 500,

    // sliding easing
    easing : 'ease-in-out',

    // the minimum number of items to show.
    // when we resize the window, this will make sure minItems are always shown
    // (unless of course minItems is higher than the total number of elements)
    minItems : 3,

    // index of the current item (left most item of the carousel)
    start : 0,

    // click item callback
    onClick : function( el, position, evt ) { return false; },
    onReady : function() { return true; },
    onBeforeSlide : function() { return false; },
    onAfterSlide : function() { return false; }

    } );            

</script>
```

Any one can help how the slider will play automaticaly? I tried autoplay: true. But, not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the scroll property,

```
scroll: 1
```

or

you can find you answer here, all type of carousel slider given

http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/

also see these

http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_auto.html

Comment: see the first link, it will give the all carousel type, see the demo you can find slider that you want.

Comment: hello there is not an auto scroll property in you slider js file, try other auto scrolling slider.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to use others slider.

Comment: The OP is not using or asking about jCarousel. 
The features you are talking about are not available in Elastislide.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a modified answer from a similar question:
[How to modify Elastislide so it loops infinitely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859998/how-to-modify-elastislide-so-it-loops-infinitely)

This will make Elastislide autoplay and when on the last slide it will return to the first slide.

**Add this code to the `$.Elastislide.defaults` object after `start : 0,`:**

```
// autoplay true || false
autoplay : true,
```

You'll then have the ability to set the `autoplay` value (true or false) when you set the options up, as you were trying to do in your example code above.

**This code should be added in the `_initEvents` function after var `self = this;`**

```
     if(this.options.autoplay == true){
            var translation = 0;
            // width/height of an item ( <li> )
            var itemSpace = this.options.orientation === 'horizontal' ? this.$items.outerWidth( true ) : this.$items.outerHeight( true );
            // total width/height of the <ul>
            var totalSpace = this.itemsCount * itemSpace;
            // visible width/height
            var visibleSpace = this.options.orientation === 'horizontal' ? this.$carousel.width() : this.$carousel.height();
            //slide auto
            window.setInterval(function(){
                //test if we should go to next slide or return to first slide
                if(totalSpace > translation + visibleSpace)
                {
                    //go to next slide
                    self._slide('next');
                    //update translation
                    translation += visibleSpace;
                }
                else
                {
                    //return to first slide
                    self._slideTo(0);
                    //set translation to 0
                    translation = 0;
                }
            }, 7000);
        }
```

---

Be aware that as Elastislide evolves past v1.1.0 this code may not work in future versions.

Comment: nice one. best answer

Answer (score 1):

For http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/

See the Autoscroll Plugin: http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/docs/plugins/autoscroll/

```
$('.jcarousel')
  .jcarousel({
    wrap: 'circular'
  })
  .jcarouselAutoscroll({
    interval: 3000,
    target: '+=1',
    autostart: true
});
```