# Jquery - Elastislide stop sliding when mouse overing

Tags: jquery, elastislide

I'm using [ELASTISLIDE – A RESPONSIVE JQUERY CAROUSEL PLUGIN](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/09/12/elastislide-responsive-carousel/)
The plugin works perfectly on my site. but i need to stop sliding when mouseover

Below code for [autoplay sliding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16973251/3264886)

```
// autoplay true || false
autoplay : true,
```

and

```
if(this.options.autoplay == true){
            var translation = 0;
            // width/height of an item ( <li> )
            var itemSpace = this.options.orientation === 'horizontal' ? this.$items.outerWidth( true ) : this.$items.outerHeight( true );
            // total width/height of the <ul>
            var totalSpace = this.itemsCount * itemSpace;
            // visible width/height
            var visibleSpace = this.options.orientation === 'horizontal' ? this.$carousel.width() : this.$carousel.height();
            //slide auto
            window.setInterval(function(){
                //test if we should go to next slide or return to first slide
                if(totalSpace > translation + visibleSpace)
                {
                    //go to next slide
                    self._slide('next');
                    //update translation
                    translation += visibleSpace;
                }
                else
                {
                    //return to first slide
                    self._slideTo(0);
                    //set translation to 0
                    translation = 0;
                }
            }, 7000);
        }
```

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1:** Add variable for timer..

```
var slide_timer; // Add variable to component
```

**2:** move `window.setInterval` part to own function (`startAutoslide`) and assign value to slide_timer in that like:

```
slide_timer = window.setInterval(function()...
```

**3:** Add `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` listeners for component. In mouseover call `clearInterval(slide_timer)` and in `onmouseout` call `startAutoslide`.

Comment: thanks but this is not working when mouseout and i fix it with other way please find my second post thanks,