# Elastislide A Responsive Carousel autoplay

Tags: jquery, html

I am using Elastic responsive jquery plugin in opencart. But its not running auto play. Here is my code:

```
    $('#carousel-latest-').elastislide({

        speed       : 450,  // animation speed
        easing      : '',   // animation easing effect
        scroll:     1,
            minItems    : 1
            });

    //Fix to adjust on windows resize
    $(window).triggerHandler('resize.elastislide');
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is it even meant to "autoplay"? Don't think so reading the website info.

Comment: http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_auto.html like this is running auto. But elastic jcarousel is not working auto..:(

Comment: So you got 2 options: Modify elastislide to make the autoplay feature or change your plugin to another

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't see any default option to auto-play, there are similar requests:

- [Tympanus Elastislide Carousel autoplay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16624041/tympanus-elastislide-carousel-autoplay)
- [How to modify Elastislide so it loops infinitely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859998/how-to-modify-elastislide-so-it-loops-infinitely)

You could modify the plugin and add auto-play support.